# How to determine if XML tags, attributes exist using Python?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find out if xml contains the subtypemismatch="true" text in the following xml.

```
<boardgames termsofuse="https://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/termsofuse">
    <boardgame objectid="45987" subtypemismatch="true">
        <yearpublished/>
```

If I use BeautifulSoup with the following code, I can get to a 'true' or 'false', but most of the xml I need to read in does not contain the subtypemismatch text, which causes a "KeyError: 'subtypemismatch'" to occur.  How do I determine if the xml has this text to begin with?

```
data = response.read()      
text = data.decode('utf-8') 
soup = BeautifulSoup(text,'xml')

if soup.find('boardgame')['subtypemismatch'] != 'true':
    do something....
```

Comment: Assuming the result of `soup.find()` implements the standard dictionary interface, something like: `if "supertypemismatch" in soup.find('boardgame') and soup.find('boardgame')['subtypemismatch'] != 'true'` or `soup.find('boardgame').get('subtypemismatch', 'true') != 'true'` might be worth a shot  (The second only calls `.find()` once -- but is sort of a bizarre use of the default argument)  If either work, post a comment and I (or someone else) can help you turn it into a respectable test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid getting `KeyError`, use `get` instead of brackets to access the attribute:

```
if soup.find('boardgame').get('subtypemismatch') != 'true':
```

If the element does not have the attribute, `get` returns `None`. You can also give it a default value:

```
if soup.find('boardgame').get('subtypemismatch', 'false') != 'true':
```

And you can also use `has_attr` to test for the existence of an attribute without getting its value:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'xml')

for boardgame in soup.find_all('boardgame'):
    if boardgame.has_attr('subtypemismatch'):
        print('has attribute')
    else:
        print('does not have attribute')
```

Comment: If they use `get` with either the default default of `None` or a default of `'false'`, they (erroneously) enter the "do something" branch of their code.